# Is the universe a closed system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, universe, quantum-gravity, multiverse

Most places say it is. But according to the multiverse hypothesis, gravitons and other quantum particles could travel from one universe to another. Wouldn't matter-energy then be transferred and thus the universe wouldn't be a closed system? Furthermore, wouldn't this violate the law of conservation of energy as the total energy is no longer constant with time?

I understand a lot of the theories dealing with this are still only theoretical, but how do they reconcile these 'paradoxes' (please do correct me of there's no paradox at all)?

Comment: Physics consists of mathematical midels approximately predicting the behavior of idealized systems under specific conditions. Please clarify which model you are referring to,  which equation and under what conditions you would like to understand better. Vague references like "closed system" without a strict definition don't mean much. Furthermore, gravitons are a hypothetical concept from the quantum theory that does not include gravity. There is no evidence either theoretical or experimental that gravitons exist. And known particles don't "tunnel" to "other universes" in conventional physics.

Comment: A box slides on the ground and comes to rest. It had kinetic energy and now that energy is gone. Would you say energy is not conserved? Or would you say your system isn't large enough to determine where that energy went?

Comment: What paradoxes have you come across which exist due to the virtue of universe being referred to as a closed system?

Answer (score -3):

The universe expanding all sided the very same now has to be a thin one galaxy thick balloon of billions of galaxies. That rather thin balloon is reality is a 100% closed system for mass, matter and energy. See documents G6, G7, G8 and G12 on [my website](http://uiterwijkwinkel.eu/english/list-of-documents/).

Comment: HEy @Uiterwijk Winkel, it's not a good answer to just have a 2 liner and then link to some other website. If possible, your answer should contain the information that is neccessary to be understood completely.

Comment: it is a comment rather than a answer.